# How to make short codes? php

Tags: php

I want to make short codes, like a wordpress...

Sample:

> [CODE]

will be replaced to

> code();

Comment: Are you looking for a templating engine?

Comment: You want a templating system, which technically, PHP already is.

Comment: Well you can say so.. yes - template engine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a templating engine.

But if you just want to replace all `[bla]` to `bla()`, you can use a regular expression:

```
$subject = '[FUNC1] [FUNC2] [FUNC3]';
$pattern = '/\[(.*)\]/U';
$replacement = '$1();';

echo preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $subject);
```

On codepad.org: http://codepad.org/v0g02dtM

Answer (score 0):

Try using a **regular expression** to find and replace anything within brackets [code] to code() before the parser kicks in.